# Infinite loop while running collect() function in Power Apps

Tags: loops, powerapps, infinite

I have the following formula:

```
// First part to collect records from a SQL database
ForAll(
    WSL_INVENT_X_LOCATION;
    If(
        Descr = drop_materiales.SelectedText.Value;
        Collect(
            colMateriales;
            ShowColumns(
                WSL_INVENT_X_LOCATION;
                "InvtID";
                "Descr";
                "WhseLoc";
                "SiteID";
                "QtyOnHand"
            )
        )
    )
);;
//Second part to remove duplicates
ClearCollect(
    colMateriales;
    ForAll(
        Distinct(
            colMateriales;
            ThisRecord
        );
        Result
    )
);;
```

The problem that I am encountering is that:

1. Infinite loop occurs while this formula runs
2. Collection only adding 0's in the column `QtyOnHand`, where in fact there are records with numbers greater than 0

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you clarify the 'infinite loop' comment in your expression? Do you know which part of the expression doesn't finish? You can add some 'Trace' statements (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-trace) and connect the monitor tool (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/monitor-overview) to see where the expression stops (or doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting some delegation limits in your query ([doc: Understanding delegation](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/delegation-overview)), which may explain why some rows are not being retrieved. You can rewrite your expression to delegate One way to avoid those would be to rewrite the expression in a way that some of the filtering is done at the server side:

```
ClearCollect(
  colMateriales;
  ShowColumns(
    Filter(
      WSL_INVENT_X_LOCATION;
      Descr = drop_materiales.SelectedText.Value);
    "InvtID";
    "Descr";
    "WhseLoc";
    "SiteID";
    "QtyOnHand"
  )
);;
```